# Ping IP address, but not on network

Tags: ping

I have a weird thing going on!  I can ping this address: xx.x.x.x but it is not on the network because I do netstat -a xx.x.x.x and it tells me that there are no hosts. Perhaps, I do not have that command line correct, but I know its something along the lines. Let's just say when I do the command to a different computer - I get success.

I try to shut it down forcefully by doing: shutdown /s /m \\xx.x.x.x and that does not work and it gives me a long error code (I do not remember because I am at home now) but I know it returns the code of 53 via command line.

Now, when I look at DHCP, it gives me the name abc-123-xyz9876 and then I try to shut it down forcefully via command line and it still does not work!!

Is someone spoofing us!?
This was brought to our attention to our firewall.

How can I stop pinging this IP address.
It does not belong to ANY of our computers.
We are a public place.

Thanks!
~Ash

Comment: To help your question, let me just say one thing: if your IPs are like 192.168.xxx.xxx or 10.xxx.xxx.xxx, you can just say them, without risking relevant information disclosure.

Answer (score 5):

> I can ping this address: xx.x.x.x but it is not on the network because I do netstat -a xx.x.x.x and it tells me that there are no hosts.

I'm not sure what you are expecting here, but `netstat -a` displays the network connections and listening ports for the computer which you are running.  It has nothing to do with remote hosts, other than that it will show you a connection if a connection is active.  This has nothing to do with mapping out your local network, and there is no guarantee that your computer will ever make a connection to that host.

> I can ping this address: xx.x.x.x but it is not on the network

That doesn't mean anything.  Whether it's on your network, or there is a route to it (such as the internet), it is somewhere.  It is considered on your network if the IP address has the same network portion of the address as yours.  If your IP address is 192.0.2.10 with a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0, and the other address was 192.0.2.250, it would be on the same network as you.  If it were 192.0.3.250, it would be on a different network.

> Now, when I look at DHCP, it gives me the name abc-123-xyz9876 and then I try to shut it down forcefully via command line and it still does not work!!

Great, we have established that this host is on your network.  Your DHCP server gave it an IP address.  That doesn't necessarily mean it's on your Windows domain which would allow you to shut it down via command line.  The TCP/IP network and the layers which Windows allows interaction with hosts are completely separate.

> Is someone spoofing us!?

This question doesn't mean much.  Please elaborate what your question if it isn't answered already.

> How can I stop pinging this IP address. It does not belong to ANY of our computers. We are a public place.

This is very simple.  Figure out where it is and remove it.  If it's not physically plugged in, it's likely your neighbor on your WiFi or something.  Change your WiFi keys.  Also ask around to see if someone plugged in a new networked printer or cell phone.